# What happens if cookies are disabled?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

Pretty basic question here. In PHP, if the user's browser has cookies disabled, you cannot make use of both server cookies (`$_SESSION`) AND client cookies (`$_COOKIE`, `setcookie`) or only the latter are disabled?
Basically you can't make the user log in or do anything that requires a session, right?

Also, in which case would someone want to have cookies disabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Both sessions and normal cookies are normal cookies. If a user does not accept cookies, he cannot use any of the functionality enabled by them. Which means pretty much the whole internet would break for that user, which is why in this day and age there's virtually nobody who has cookies disabled entirely.

PHP has a built-in mechanism called [transparent session ids](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php), which automagically rewrites all links to contain the session id in a query parameter. I would not suggest using it, since session ids in the URL open up a whole new can of worms.

For user friendliness, I'd recommend you test whether the user has cookies enabled or not (set a cookie, redirect to the next page with a flag in the URL that cookies *should* be set, see if you get any cookies back) and if not, kindly advise the user to enable them.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Random thought.. do you think trans-sid might be acceptable combined with SSL though? (since the query parameters are ssl'ed) ?

Comment: @Ben The problem is not really the lack of SSL, it's that the user won't understand that the URL contains a session and sends an URL containing the trans-sid to a friend. Clicking the link will log the friend in as the user.

Comment: @Ben No. The problem is not about *visibility*. A cookie is just as visible as a URL, if somebody is in a position to intercept either. The problem is with sharing URLs, having them in the browser history etc.

Comment: @both. Yes, very good point, I totally overlooked that aspect

Comment: I have cookies disabled entirely. I enable them on a site-by-site basis. It's not too bad.

Comment: @Boann That's why I worded that carefully to say *"virtually"* and *"entirely"*. If you enable them as needed, that's not really *"entirely disabled"*... :)

Comment: Great answer! and yes, advising the user to enable them is the method that Facebook, Twitter and many other important services use, so I'll stick to it

Answer (score 2):

You can track the user by `$_GET`.

Imagine that on every-single-page the user visits you pass a `?user_id=XYZ123` then you would have implemented a very similar server-identification. It has obvious disadvantages:

1. if you copy/paste a URL you'll give away your session_id
2. because of 1 session high-jack is even less tech savy

**Why do users disable cookies?**
Users tend to throw first and third party cookies all in the mix but they come from different breeds.

First party cookies are generally ok. When you visit Facebook it's expected that Facebook keeps a cookie to store your interactions with the server.

What it's not expected is that the advertising company that has adds both on Facebook and on eBay gets your cookie back and checks, ah, so this guy was on eBay looking for xyz so now that he's on Facebook I'm gonna show him up abc to make him buy etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the session reference manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

In short, if your server can't find session_id, he can not restore session. But you can use alternate ways to store session values. Or you can generate session_od base on user's client environment parameters.